# \multirow to fit a figure into a table in a tikzposter

Tags: tables, multirow, tikzposter

I'm trying to use `\multirow` to fit a figure into a table in a tikzposter style document and can't quite figure it out. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[24pt, a1paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\title{\textbf{title}}
\author{me}
\date{}
\institute{\small{institute}}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{columns}
\column{0.7}
\block{Block Title}
{
Some Text.

\begin{tikzfigure}
\begin{tabular}{ p{6cm}|p{6cm}|p{6cm}}
\hline
\hline
Partial Pressure of Water (mbar) & Decay Lifetime '$\tau_{decay}$' (ms) & 
\multirow{5}
{ 
\begin{tikzfigure} 
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{sample}
\end{tikzfigure}} \\
\hline
 $5.17\times10^{-6}$ & $0.48$ & \\
 $5.13\times10^{-7}$ & $0.95$ & \\
 $2.40\times10^{-8}$ & $0.91$ & \\
 $5.07\times10^{-8}$ & $1.0$ & \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tikzfigure}

 }
\end{columns}


\end{document}
```

I receive the following error, which I don't understand:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 7030) in paragraph at lines 48--48
[]\T1/aer/m/n/29.86 Partial Pres-
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 48--48
[]\T1/aer/m/n/29.86 Decay Life-
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 48--48
\T1/aer/m/n/29.86 time '$\OML/cmm/m/it/29.86 []$\T1/aer/m/n/29.86 '
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.48 }
?
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the `tikzfigure` environment around the `\includegraphics` command? Apart from that, your `\multirow` command misses its second argument: `\multirow{<number of rows>}{<width>}{<content>}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution assuming that the images should be the column header of the third column.

[image]

I have used the following:

- `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and `valign=c` to vertically center the image in the column header
- `wc{6cm}` from the `array` package to achieve a column that is 6cm wide and horizontally centered
- the `S` type column from `siunitx` for an improved alignment (and easier input) of numbers
- the `makecell` package for the linebreaks in teh column headers of the first and second column.
- removed the `24pt` class option as this is unknown (see warning).

```
\documentclass[a1paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}


\begin{columns}
\column{0.7}
\block{Block Title}
{
Some Text.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ S[table-format=1.2e-1]|S[table-format=1.2]|wc{6cm}}
\hline
\hline
{\makecell[cc]{Partial Pressure \\ of Water (\si{\milli\bar})}} & {\makecell[cc]{Decay Lifetime \\ $\tau_{\text{decay}}$ (\si{\milli\second})}} & \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{example-image}\\
\hline
 5.17e-6 & 0.48 & \\
 5.13e-7 & 0.95 & \\
 2.40e-8 & 0.91 & \\
 5.07e-8 & 1.0 & \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
 }
\end{columns}


\end{document}
```

---

Regarding the code in your question: First of all, I don't get the same messages as you. If I fix the `\multirow` command, that misses its second argument (`\multirow{<number of rows>}{<width>}{<content>}`) and use `\multirow{5}{=}{...}` the code becomes compilable and I get several warnings about underfull boxes. These are generated because content in `p` type columns is by default justified and your column width is too small to achieve a good justified alignment. You can see a huge white space in the column header of the second column between decay and lifetime. I would therefor recommend to use a different alignment for the column headers.